# How can I pass data from parent to nested components?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I'm creating a Vue3 web app and I was wondering what is the best way to pass data from parent to nested components (more specific, from parent to child of children).

Let's say I have this schema:

```
       Card
         |
         |
  CardHeader     CardBody
                    |
                    |
   BodyHeader  BodyParams  BodyResponse
```

And I want to know the best way to pass data from Card to BodyHeader, BodyParams and BodyResponse

On  `Card Component` I will be fetching some data from an API. Lets say that i fetch a json like this:

```
{
  header: {
    title: 'hello header'
  },
  body: {
    headers: ['authorization', 'anotherheader']
    params: ['currency', 'hair'],
    response: ['200', '401']
  }
}
```

I know I just could do this:

`<Card/>` :

```
<template>
  <CardHeader :header="hedaer"></CardHeader>
  <CardBody :body="body"></CardBody> 
</template>
```

Then, in `<CardBody/>` :

```
<template>
  <CardBodyHeader :headers="body.headers"></CardBodyHeader>
  <CardBodyParams :params="body.params"></CardBodyParams>
  <CardBodyResponse :responses="body.responses"></CardBodyResponse>
</template>

<script>
import CardBodyHeader from "./CardBodyHeader.vue";
import CardBodyParams from "./CardBodyParams.vue";
import CardBodyResponse from "./CardBodyResponse.vue";

export default {
  components: { CardBodyHeader, CardBodyParams, CardBodyResponse },
  props: {
    body: {type: Object}
  }
};
</script>
```

But I don't know if that would be the optimal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there are many ways, you could do that.

Easiest one would be **state management**, and you can use something like **Pinia** and **Vuex** to do so or maybe even **write your own store** (But why do that when you have Pinia).

Second one would be the usage of **props**, but you should keep in mind that props  should never be mutated.
**==> https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html**

Third one would be the use of Vue3 **(Provide / Inject)** as seen on the docs **==> https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html**

You can also send data from a child to a parent component Vue's built-in **$emit()** method.

But of course **each and every one of these is solving different problems**, so try to have a quick read on docs about each and every one of them to solve the issue you're facing, and to know which to use on the upcoming issues you might face.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use any state management library like `Vuex` or `pinia`.

I suggest you to use [`provide/inject`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#prop-drilling) to prevent props drilling.

You need to `provide` the data from the most parent component, and in the child components that need these data, just use `inject`

Ex parent:

```
export default {
  provide: {
    message: 'hello!'
  }
}
```

Ex: nested child

```
export default {
  inject: ['message'],
  created() {
    console.log(this.message) // injected value
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to know, if I used a pinia store, where  i have array of objets like the one I described above, then I would be doing something like <Card v-for="element in cardStore.cards"/> and I could potentially have props drilling too, right?

Comment: @AlvaroNavarretePozueco why you will have `props drilling`? you will just get the data in the component you need it in without any props.